# How to update recurly subscription price on next renewal date?

Tags: subscription, price, recurly

Using the Recurly python SDK, modify the subscription price not immediately but o the next billing date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [Recurly docs](https://dev.recurly.com/docs/lookup-subscription-details)
Using the Recurly python SDK you can set the subscription **timeframe** value to **bill_date** below a python SDK example.

```
subscription = recurly.Subscription.get(subscription_uuid)
subscription.unit_amount_in_cents = unit_amount_in_cents
subscription.timeframe = 'bill_date'
subscription.save()
```

This will cause the pricing update occur on the next billing date and not immediate.